# An invalid character[44] was present in the Cookie value

Tags: java, tomcat8

When using Tomcat 8 
Getting Error :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [44] was present in the Cookie value
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateCookieValue(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:386)

Comment: What is a question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you adding any cookies, during that time the exception occurs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character `0x44` is comma character and it is not allowed in cookies:

> This string is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space.

The reference comes from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error in my project with Tomcat 8 and 9. The easiest but less optimal solution was to change to Tomcat 7, but when this version of Tomcat is deprecated or updated on the server I will have to go find all the commas and replace them in the cookie setting.